# Swift - Reading JSON File

Tags: json, swift

I'm new to Swift - trying to read a JSON file from a URL. My attempt below.

The JSON looks valid - I tested it with JSONLint but it keeps crashing.

Thoughts?

```
func getRemoteJsonFile() -> NSDictionary {
    //Create a new url

    let remoteUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://nfl-api.azurewebsites.net/myplayers.json")

    //check if its nil
    if let actualRemoteUrl = remoteUrl {

        //try to get the data
        let filedata:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: actualRemoteUrl)

            //check if its nil
        if let actualFileData = filedata {

            //parse out the dictionaries
            let jsonDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(actualFileData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as NSDictionary

            return jsonDict
        }
    }
        return NSDictionary()
}
```

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x102475138)

Comment: Have you heard about optionals?

Comment: Why not using SwiftyJSON instead NSDictionary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with this:

```
func getRemoteJsonFile() -> [NSDictionary] {

    // Create a new URL
    let remoteUrl:NSURL? = NSURL(string: "http://nfl-api.azurewebsites.net/myplayers.json")

    let urlString:String = "\(remoteUrl)"

    // Check if it's nil
    if let actualRemoteUrl = remoteUrl {

        // Try to get the data
        let fileData:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: actualRemoteUrl)

        // Check if it's nil
        if let actualFileData = fileData {

            // Parse out the dictionaries
            let arrayOfDictionaries:[NSDictionary]? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(actualFileData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [NSDictionary]?

            if let actualArrayOfDictionaries = arrayOfDictionaries {

                // Successfully parsed out array of dictionaries
                return actualArrayOfDictionaries
            }
        }

    }
    return [NSDictionary]()
}
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: please mention into comment why are you down voting my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This took me a second to figure out, so I don't blame you for missing it.

The JSON you linked to is minified, so it's difficult to see the structure. Let's take a look at (a fragment of) it after piping it through [a prettifier](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com):

```json
[
   {
      "PlayerId":2501863,
      "PlayerName":"Peyton Manning",
      "PlayerTeam":"DEN",
      "PlayerPosition":"QB",
      "PlayerPassingYards":4727,
      "PlayerPassingTDs":39,
      "PlayerInterceptions":15,
      "PlayerRushingYards":-24,
      "PlayerRushingTDs":0,
      "PlayerReceivingYards":0,
      "PlayerReceivingTDs":0,
      "PlayerReturnYards":0,
      "PlayerReturnTDs":0,
      "PlayerFumbleTDs":0,
      "PlayerTwoPointConversions":2,
      "PlayerFumblesLost":2,
      "PlayerTeamLogo":"http://i.nflcdn.com/static/site/7.0/img/logos/teams-gloss-81x54/den.png"
   }
]
```

Huh. It's encased in brackets, which means that it's an **array**.

It's an array, so *you can't cast it as an `NSDictionary`*. Instead, you could cast it as an `NSArray`, but why not use native Swift types?

Well, if you don't like types, you're about to find out, but I still think that this is a better way, because it forces you to think about the data you're parsing.

So we have the first part of our type definition for this function; it's an array (`[]`). What components is our array made up of? We could go with a simple `NSDictionary`, but we're doing full native types here, so let's use [a native Swift dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113).

To do that, we have to know the types of the dictionary (the syntax for a native dictionary type is `[KeyType: ValueType]`). Examining the JSON shows that all of the keys are `String`s, but the values are of varying types, so we can use `AnyObject`.

That gives us a dictionary type of `[String: AnyObject]`, and our entire JSON is an array of that, so the final type is `[[String: AnyObject]]` (wow).

---

Now that we have the proper type, we can modify the function you're using to parse the JSON a bit.

First of all, let's use our new type for the return and cast values. Then, let's make the return type [optional](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) in case something goes wrong and add an `error` variable to document that.

A cleaned up function would look something like this:

```swift
func getData() -> [[String: AnyObject]]? {
    let data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://nfl-api.azurewebsites.net/myplayers.json")!)
    if let req: NSData = data {
        var error: NSError?
        if let JSON: [[String: AnyObject]] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(req, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: &error) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            return JSON
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

That's it!

We can now call the function and extract values from our `[[String: AnyObject]]` (again, wow) like this:

```
if let data: [[String: AnyObject]] = getData() {
    println(data[0]["PlayerName"]!) // Peyton Manning
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Beautifully written.